# How do I revert / undo a `session.execute()` statement in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope

If I would like to undo a previous update statement executed with `session.execute(my_update_sql)` statement on a SQLAlchemy session, how do I go about it?

I am using SQLAlchemy, Zope in a Pyramid web application

Comment: Why would you exactly need that? What is your use case?

Comment: If `session.execute` hasn't commited then you can `session.rollback`

Comment: I though `session.execute` always commits, isn't that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that you use a "real" DBMS with transactions, you should be able to roll back the current transaction, just as you would do with other operations involving `session`:

```
session.execute('DELETE FROM users')  # feel the thrill!
session.rollback()
```

A typical setup of SQLAlchemy with Pyramid involves ZopeTransactionExtension, which integrates session management with Pyramid's request-response cycle. In this case, to roll back the transaction you'll need to do that using ZTE's transaction manager:

```
import transaction
transaction.rollback()
```

Note that rolling back the transaction will undo ALL changes made in the transaction, not only your `session.execute()` statement. If you only want to "undo" just one statement you can try using SQLAlchemy's [nested transactions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint), support for which depends on the DBMS you're using,